# Extracting Wallet IDs (Public Keys) from Bitcoin Blockchain Data Structures

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, blockchain.info-api, nbitcoin

I'm trying to locate the public keys associated with a Bitcoin block's transaction inputs and outputs.

Can anyone tell me where those are encoded?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say they all work correctly and I didn't do multisig but this is what I have using NBitcoin:

```
public static string? GetScriptPubKey(this TxOut txOut)
{
    if (txOut.ScriptPubKey.FindTemplate() is PayToWitTemplate p2w)
        return p2w.ExtractScriptPubKeyParameters(txOut.ScriptPubKey)?.GetAddress(Network.Main).ToString();

    if (txOut.ScriptPubKey.FindTemplate() is PayToScriptHashTemplate p2sh)
        return p2sh.ExtractScriptPubKeyParameters(txOut.ScriptPubKey)?.GetAddress(Network.Main).ToString();

    if (txOut.ScriptPubKey.FindTemplate() is PayToTaprootTemplate p2t)
        return p2t.ExtractScriptPubKeyParameters(txOut.ScriptPubKey)?.GetAddress(Network.Main).ToString();

    if (txOut.ScriptPubKey.FindTemplate() is PayToPubkeyHashTemplate p2pkh)
        return p2pkh.ExtractScriptPubKeyParameters(txOut.ScriptPubKey)?.GetAddress(Network.Main).ToString();

    if (txOut.ScriptPubKey.FindTemplate() is PayToPubkeyTemplate p2pk)
        return p2pk.ExtractScriptPubKeyParameters(txOut.ScriptPubKey).ToString();

    if (txOut.ScriptPubKey.FindTemplate() is PayToWitPubKeyHashTemplate p2wpkh)
        return p2wpkh.ExtractScriptPubKeyParameters(txOut.ScriptPubKey)?.GetAddress(Network.Main).ToString();

    if (txOut.ScriptPubKey.FindTemplate() is PayToWitScriptHashTemplate p2wsh)
        return p2wsh.ExtractScriptPubKeyParameters(txOut.ScriptPubKey)?.GetAddress(Network.Main).ToString();

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, in general you can't.

Depending on the signature schema, all you could get would be a *hash* of that public key, or, even worse, a *hash* of a *redeem script*.

More specifically, you could get *some* public keys in some cases.
This is a partial list of what you could get:

1. Pay-to-pubkey-hash scripts (P2PKH): you get the public key from the scriptSig for the input BTC address
2. Pay-to-pubkey (P2PK): you get the public key from scriptPubKey for the output BTC address
3. Pay-to-script-hash scripts (P2SH): you get the public *keys* from the scriptSig for the input BTC address

There are other signature schemes and in *standard* transactions you should be able to get *either* the source public key *or* the destination public key.

What you could do is indexing the whole blockchain and fill the gaps in transactions where BTC addresses are not included together with their public key. But, for instance, if your BTC address appears only in P2PKH outputs, you have no means to find that public key.

Comment: But how can the Bitcoin system track the balances in accounts if the public keys aren't available in the transactions? How do those sites work that allow you to query the balance in an account via its public key? (I googled for this one: https://bitref.com). TY for your previous kind reply and any further help with this.

Comment: Bitcoin as a network of `bitcoind` nodes does not track balances at all. All it does is enforce the _consensus_ rules_.
There is no such association between:
1. accounts and public keys
2. accounts and BTC addresses
3. BTC addresses and balance

The wallet support that you might have found in `bitcoind` just keeps track of all its relevant addresses. It requires specific indexing (e.g. if you import keys from external you have to reindex it).

Comment: Try to think of bitcoin as a collection of outputs that can be redeemed by executing cryptographic scripts. The balance is thus the sum of unspent outputs associated to a specific address.
Just to be clear, each private ECDSA key has a corresponding public key. A BTC address is a _hash_ of that public key. Thus, if you are implementing a wallet, you can easily track down all the outputs associated to that key and ultimately to your BTC address.

Comment: Ok.
Are these two statements true? 
1) "Account" is an abstraction that wallet software provides.

2) A bitcoin address is a hash of a public key, and thus the system validates that transfers have sufficient balances by unhashing the public key when a transaction is submitted encoded with the corresponding private key.

Does this mean that every address (every hashed public key) can only correspond to one public key? In other words, I guess this means that the hash is guaranteed to be unique for each public key, right?

Ty

Comment: 1. Correct
2. More precisely, `bitcoind` verifies the _consensus rules_ (e.g. an output cannot be spent twice). A wallet normally creates a transaction provided that it has enough unspent outputs to send the specified amount of BTC. The user has typically the view of total balance, so he does not see what the wallet system does under the hood.

Let's say that each public key has only one BTC address. This does not apply for every address type, but that's most of the case.

Comment: So...Bitcoin nodes don't explicitly track the balances available to addresses. To validate a transaction, they simply verify that its inputs are comprised of unused outputs and those outputs are associated with the public key of the sending address. A "balance" can only be computed, by summing the unused outputs currently available to an address. Is that about right? Ty.

Also, why even hash the public keys? Does it possibly reduce size? Or is there a bit of error checking added, after the fashion of a parity check?

Ty once more kind sir.

Comment: Correct: most of the work of a wallet is to denormalize the blockchain. So, yes, the "balance" is a sum of the unspent outputs. Wallets also define the concept of unconfirmed balance and confirmed balance, depending of the inclusion height.
Also, it is important to understand that BTC addresses have nothing to do with Bitcoin, or at least not directly: transactions do not contain addresses but hashes of public addresses. By knowing just the hash of a public key, anyone can send Bitcoin to the corresponding address. A BTC address is just a Base58 conversion of that hash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185917/discussion-between-fcracker79-and-padawan-learner).